# Golang how to validate user input for only int

Tags: go, integer

is there a way to scan only integers in Go? like an age or a number of order etc. so you don't want user to enter letters or signs.
Scanf apparently don't work, it get skipped and print instead  "unexpected newline"

```
func AgeInput(age int) {
fmt.Println("enter your Age :..")


     _, err := fmt.Scanf("%d", &UserAge)

     if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
     }
```

}

I also tried to use contains and containsAny to check if the input has any numbers and if not then it is not valid and the user will be asked to try again but it returns either always true or always false

```
func ValidateAge(age int){
AgeInput(age)
if strings.Contains(strconv.Itoa(UserAge), "1234567890"){
    validAge = true
}
for !validAge {
    fmt.Println("wrong input try again")
    AgeInput(age)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think you were on the right track here, but just need to tweak you code a little:

```golang
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Enter your Age: ")

    var userAge int
    for true {
        _, err := fmt.Scanf("%d", &userAge)
        if err == nil {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("Not a valid age - try again")
        var dump string
        fmt.Scanln(&dump)
    }

    fmt.Println(userAge)
}
```

Scanf only scans until it gets a match, but will leave the rest of the line untouched, so we need to clear the STDIN buffer with a fmt.Scanln